# Delete string up to last slash

Tags: xstring

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\StrBehind[2]{/foo/bar}{/}
\StrCount{/foo/bar}{/}
\StrBehind[\StrCount{/foo/bar}{/}]{/foo/bar}{/}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to delete `/foo/` out of `/foo/bar` using `xstring`. The first line in the document above does produce `bar` and the second line does produce `2`, but the third line doesn't work. How do I make it work, or is there a simpler approach to do what I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand well what do you want: to expand the last segment separated by slashes from the parameter, i.e. `/foo/bar` should expand to `bar` and `/foo/bar/next` should expand to `next`. You can define following macro (using only TeX primitives):

```
\def\afterlastslash#1{\afterlsA#1/\end}
\def\afterlsA#1/#2{\ifx#2\end #1\else \expandafter\afterlsA\expandafter#2\fi}

\afterlastslash{/foo/bar}       % expands to bar

\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/next}  % expands to next
```

Comment: This is great. I like that it is plain TeX. (It also shows a recursive pattern I might be able to use for other things.)

Answer (score 7):

I think a `listofitems` approach is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar[,]{/}%
\newcommand\postslash[1]{\readlist\myparse{#1}\myparse[-1]}
\begin{document}
\postslash{/foo/bar}

\postslash{bar}

\postslash{/foo/baz/bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried doing the same thing with `\expandafter`s, with no sucess.  Besides, that much inline code is ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\StrCount{/foo/bar}{/}[\temp]
\StrBehind[\temp]{/foo/bar}{/}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function StrBehind(s0)
    local s1 = s0:split("/")
    tex.print(s1[#s1])
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\StrBehind[1]{\directlua{StrBehind("#1")}}
\begin{document}
\StrBehind{/foo/bar}
    
\StrBehind{/foo/bar/bza/foobar}

\StrBehind{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `expl3` implementation, named `\getbasename`. We add `/\q_nil/` at the end and test two items at a time (the first can be empty).

Similarly defined is `\getdirname` that returns the path.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getbasename}{m}
 {
  \michel_getbasename:w #1/\q_nil/
 }
\cs_new:Npn \michel_getbasename:w #1/#2/
 {
  \quark_if_nil:nTF { #2 }
   {% reached the end, return the previous item
    #1
   }
   {% go on: put back #2/ and test again
    \michel_getbasename:w #2/
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdirname}{m}
 {
  \michel_getdirname:w #1/\q_nil/
 }
\cs_new:Npn \michel_getdirname:w #1/#2/
 {
  \quark_if_nil:nF { #2 }
   {% return #1/ and go on: put back #2/ and test again
    #1/
    \michel_getdirname:w #2/
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getbasename{/foo/bar}

\getbasename{foo/bar}

\getbasename{/foo//bar}

\getbasename{/foo/bar/next}

X\getbasename{}X

X\getbasename{/}X

X\getbasename{/foo/}X

\getdirname{/foo/bar}

\getdirname{foo/bar}

\getdirname{/foo//bar}

\getdirname{/foo/bar/next}

X\getdirname{}X

\getdirname{/}

\getdirname{/foo/}

\end{document}
```

The last three examples with `\getbasename` and the first one with `\getdirname` return nothing, as witnessed by “XX”.

[image]

The function `\quark_if_nil:nTF` returns true if its (braced) argument contains only `\q_nil`, false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a another approach using underlying TeX capacity with delimited macros.  Compared to [answer by wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684771/293669) it is not using conditional tests (which may fail fo various reasons such as braced material, I will give an example), but it also proceeds iteratively and expandably.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for \texttt{->}

\makeatletter

\catcode`A 3 % create some improbable token as delimiter
             % as we are using LaTeX for the demo, perhaps
             % we should have used \@nil

% switch utility
\long\def\uppera@switch #1A#2#3\relax{#2}

% we incorporate slight overhead to expand in exactly two steps
\long\def\afterlastslash#1{\romannumeral\afterlastslash@i \z@#1/A}
\long\def\afterlastslash@i #1/#2{\uppera@switch #2{#1}A{\afterlastslash@i\z@#2}\relax}

\catcode`A 11
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand\test[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{\afterlastslash{#1}}} expands to \texttt{\afterlastslash{#1}}}

\test{/oof/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{/{oof}/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{{braced/path}/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{{/path}/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{/foo/bar/next}  % expands to next


\newcommand\testedef[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{\edef\x{\afterlastslash{#1}}}} gives meaning
            \edef\x{\afterlastslash{#1}}\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}}

\testedef{/foo/bar/next}

\testedef{/foo/bar/next/}

Check that two expansions suffice

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\x
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/next}}
\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}


Show feature of brace removal of output
% a limitation: there is brace removal of last part
\edef\x{\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/{next}}}\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}

Check nesting. We need te expand argument, but our macro was not constructed
to expand it.  So let's use \texttt{\string\expanded} and
\texttt{\string\expandafter}.
\begin{verbatim}
\edef\x{\expandafter\afterlastslash\expandafter{%
        \expanded{\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/{/foo/bar}}}}}
\end{verbatim}
%
\edef\x{\expandafter\afterlastslash\expandafter{\expanded{\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/{/foo/bar}}}}}\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code 1]

##### Variant which makes sure to protect output from brace removal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for \texttt{->}

\makeatletter

\catcode`A 3 % create some improbable token as delimiter
             % as we are using LaTeX for the demo, perhaps
             % we should have used \@nil

% switch utility
\long\def\uppera@switch #1A#2#3\uppera@switch{#2}

% we incorporate slight overhead to expand in exactly two steps
% also we avoid brace removal of last item in this variant
% (thanks to extending it by \@nil and also by fetching two
% items at a time)

\long\def\afterlastslash#1{\romannumeral\afterlastslash@i#1\@nil/A/}
\long\def\afterlastslash@i #1/#2/{%
     % notice that brace removal can happen in intermediate #2 but this
     % is not important, as the final  "basename" is protected by the added \@nil
     \uppera@switch #2{\afterlastslash@clean\@empty#1}A{\afterlastslash@i#2/}\uppera@switch
}
% \@empty token will prevent brace removal in this last step
\long\def\afterlastslash@clean#1\@nil{\expandafter\z@#1}

\catcode`A 11
\makeatother

% wipet https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684771/293669
% \def\afterlastslash#1{\afterlsA#1/\end}
% \def\afterlsA#1/#2{\ifx#2\end #1\else \expandafter\afterlsA\expandafter#2\fi}

\begin{document}



\newcommand\test[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{\afterlastslash{#1}}} expands to \texttt{\afterlastslash{#1}}}

\test{/oof/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{/{oof}/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{{braced/path}/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{{/path}/bar}     % expands to bar

\test{/foo/bar/next}  % expands to next


\newcommand\testedef[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{\edef\x{\afterlastslash{#1}}}} gives meaning
            \edef\x{\afterlastslash{#1}}\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}}

\testedef{/foo/bar/next}

\testedef{/foo/bar/next/}

Check that two expansions suffice

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\x
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/next}}
\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}


Check no brace removal regarding last item
\edef\x{\afterlastslash{/foo/bar/{last is kept braced}}}\texttt{\meaning\x<after meaning>}

\end{document}
```

output

[image]